# Finding the area under the graph (integration)

Tags: integration

[image: I blurred the irrelevant part]

I just wanted to ask, shouldn't the value of $y$ change since the height of each rectangles are different? So why is the sum of all the strips equal to $  \sum y \delta x$? Isn't that telling us that $y$ is the same for every rectangle?

Also, how did they go from

$$\lim_{\delta x \to 0 } \sum y \delta x$$
to
$$A = \int y \ dx$$

How did the integral symbol appear? I thought we use the integral symbol to find the equation of the function. Does that mean $ \sum y \delta x \ $ is the slope of the function?

Thank you. I'm sorry for the bad explanation

Comment: It changes, indeed! $y$ is a function of $x$ and the integral means that you "multiply" the base $\delta x$ by the height $y(x)$ and "Sum" the rectangles: $\sum y(x)\cdot \delta x$ BTW $\int$ is a distortion of the letter $S$.
If that is your textbook throw it in the fireplace...

Comment: I agree with Raffaele on the awful quality of the textbook

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The value of $y$ does change as you say, it's implicit that $y=f(x)$ is a function of $x$. You can write $y(x)$ if it's more clear to you. And the integral symbol appeared because the limit of that sum is the *definition* of the Riemann integral. To be more specific, you can cut your functions in rectangles in two different ways: either like in the figure, so that the left corner of the rectangle touches the curve, or so that the right corner touches it.

[image]

In the picture, the blue rectangles are the first way, the red ones are the second way.

Say your function is defined on the interval $[a,b]$. Define $\delta x=\frac{b-a}{n}$ and $x_k=a+k\delta x$ for $k=1,2,\dots, n$, this is the k-position of the k-th rectangle. We can write the sum of the areas of the two kinds of rectangle this way. For the blue:

$$S_l(n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^n f(x_k)\delta x$$
It's the height of the rectangle,$f(x)$, multiplied by its base $\delta x$. This is called the Riemann left sum. For the red
$$S_r(n)= \sum\limits_{k=0}^{n-1} f(x_k+\delta x)\delta x$$
It's again the height of the rectangle,$f(x+ \delta x)$, because we are taking the right corner this time, multiplied by its base $\delta x$. This is called the Riemann right sum.

You can see that as $n$ increases, both sums approach the area under the curve. But mathematicians want to be precise, so let $n$ go to infinity, if $$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_r \qquad \lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_l $$
both exist and

$$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_r =\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_l$$

Then we say that $f$ is *Riemann integrable* and we write

$$ \int_a^b f(x) \mathrm{d}x=\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_r =\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty} S_l $$

The integral sign appears because this is the *definition* of the integral. Some introductory courses like to present the integral as an antiderivative, but the fact that $$ \int_a^b f'(x)\mathrm{d}x=f(b)-f(a) $$
if $f$ is differentiable is a theorem, called the fundamental theorem of calculus, that can be proven starting from this definition and some other theorems about continuous and differentiable functions.

As a side note, if you are curious about just what the heck do areas have to do with slopes, I suggest you watch the youtube series "The essence of calculus" by the channel 3Blue1Brown, it's a wonderful intuitive and visual little introduction to the basic ideas of calculus and covers this and other problems.